# Error compile tfs indexed source

Tags: tfs, build

I am getting the next error when i try build in TFS2013:

Indexed source information could not be retrieved from C:\Builds\2\Company\Solution\Binaries\Antlr3.Runtime.pdb. Error: Symbol indexes could not be retrieved.

the files exist in path.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an incompatibility and you will have to delete that pdb.

You should not have a binaries folder. It is bad practice to check binaries into source control. You should replace all your binary references with NuGet Package references. Likley an updated pdb would work. If you use NuGet you will have the latest version of Antlr.

Answer (score 12):

I "fixed" this error by setting the following property to `false` on my TFS build definition:

Process -> Source And Symbol Server Settings -> Index Sources.

[image]

Some additional information about what *Index Sources* does is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops) (emphasis mine)

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to index your source code
>   and optionally publish symbols to the Package Management symbol server
>   or a file share.
>
> **Indexing source code enables you to use your .pdb symbol files to
>   debug an app on a machine other than the one you used to build the
>   app.** For example, you can debug an app built by a build agent from a
>   dev machine that does not have the source code.
>
> Symbol servers enables your debugger to automatically retrieve the
>   correct symbol files without knowing product names, build numbers or
>   package names. To learn more about symbols, read the concept page; to
>   publish symbols, use this task and see the walkthrough.

Comment: Trying to find that property.  Is it a property of the build as a whole, or of a particular step?

Comment: @WilliamJockusch I've added a picture to make it clear.

Comment: @RB. Can you please give some more information about this? what exactly it does and all?

Answer (score 2):

Selecting the option to skip index fixed my problem. Follow the example below.

[image]